# Upload file from Google Drive to S3 Server using php

Tags: php, amazon-s3, google-api-php-client

I want to upload file from google drive to S3 server. I used Google Picker to select file from google drive. Unfortunately, I have difficulty to upload file to s3 after select file.

I used file_get_contents(file_url) and then upload to s3 server. It working fine in dropbox api. But I can't get content form google drive returned url.

Could you please share me the idea and suggestions?

Comment: If you are looking for assistance with your code you will need to show us your code.

Comment: $binary = file_get_contents('https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=[file_id]');
             $result = $this->s3Client->putObject(array(
                'Bucket' => $bucket_name,
                'Key' => $filename,
                'Body'   => $binary,              
                'ContentType' => $content_type,
                'ACL' => 'public-read',
                'StorageClass' => 'REDUCED_REDUNDANCY',
                'Metadata' => array(
                    'param1' => 'value 1',
                    'param2' => 'value 2'
                )
                    ));

Answer (score 0):

try this S3 Class:  [s3 class](http://%20http://s3.amazonaws.com/awsdownloads/s3video.zip)

```
<?php
require( "s3.class.php" );
$contents = file_get_contents(file_url);
$s3svc = new S3();
$s3svc->putBucket('bucketName');
$objs = $s3svc->getObjects('bucketName');
$out = $s3svc->putObject( $filename, $contents, 'bucketName',$permissions, $fileType );
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.Yes,I try like this. Google drive link is https://docs.google.com/uc?export=view&id=[file_id].When I use file_get_contents,show error.

Comment: https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/blob/master/examples/fileupload.php#L25     https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/get